# How to face character in its movement direction and at the same time keep it aligned to any surface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move my player character(human) on a curved surface. But at the same time character shall stay perpendicular to the surface normals and it should face in the movement direction and can handle collisions(if there is a wall ahead, shall not be able to go through it).

I tried to make a parent stay over normals and change the child local rotation towards direction of motion of its parent. But it has several  limitations as of now.
Here is the code what i was using:

```
[SerializeField] float raycastLength = 1f;
bool canPlayerMove = true;
public float speed = 2f;
public Vector3 offset; //object's position offset to ground / surface
public Quaternion childDirection;
private void Update()
{
    float moveHorizontal = SimpleInput.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = SimpleInput.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);
    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, raycastLength))
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
        transform.position = hitInfo.point + offset;
        Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hitInfo.point, Color.red);

    }
    if (canPlayerMove)
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0, moveVertical);
        if (movement != Vector3.zero)
        {
            childDirection = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.GetChild(0).localRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(movement), 0.15F);
            transform.GetChild(0).localRotation = childDirection;
        }
        transform.Translate(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first to not make your player go thru walls you want to add a collider to your walls and not set it as trigger, you will also need a rigidbody on your player and this will help in the next steps.

Secondly you will need to acces the rigidBody in code using this: (if you Check *Use Gravity* it will also stay on your terrain that you made)

```
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float speed = 7.5f;

private void Start()
{
    //this gets the rigidbody on the gameObject the script is currently on.
    rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}



 private void Update()
 {
      float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      float vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
     
     //this will move your player frame independent.
     rb.MovePosition(this.transform.position + new Vector3(hor, 0, vert) * speed * 
     Time.deltaTime);
  }
```

Also make sure that you have a rigidBody on your player, else it will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jadon. But there is small issue with the answer or may be i need to add some more details in question. Like i needed to keep my character aligned to any surface and this won't help when surface is suppose spherical. I need bit more complex solution something like using surface normals or some other mathematics to calculate what shape of surface player is standing on(like player standing on bottom of sphere and feet still on its surface)

Comment: what you could try to do is to add a gravity force towards the surface in question. so if it is a sphere you should add a force to the sphere's middle

Comment: yeah jadon. But i need it for any shape regardless of a sphere, cube, or any irregular shape. I think adding gravity towards any object's middle will not be the right solution.

Comment: It's ok Jadon. Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: i dont know much about the physics engine.